# UITableViewCell Storyboard Registration Dependent on Initial View Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

In my current XCode project, I have two view controllers. The first, the initial view controller, just has a button. The second view controller is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. I defined a custom table view cell in the storyboard, gave it a reuse identifier, and defined a custom class and hooked up the relevant IBOutlets.

After launching the app, when the button is pressed, the second view controller is modally presented on top of the first one via `self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`. The two view controllers are not connected in the storyboard by a segue. After this modal segue, during the construction of the table, it crashes with the error:

`'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier PlaylistCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

However, when the table view controller is the initial view controller, it does not crash and displays all of the data correctly. I'm wondering if the nib registration is dependent on the view controller being connected to the initial view controller through the storyboard?

EDIT: I figured out my error. For other people who find themselves in this problem, I was initializing my second view controller like:

`let vc = SecondViewController()`

But you have to intialize it like this if you design it via Storyboard:

`let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController")`

Answer (score 0):

As you have figured out, you have to instantiate the table view controller by identifying it in the storyboard.

If the storyboard for second controller is the same as for the first one, you can do this as well:

```
if let storyboard = self.storyboard, controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Second") as? UITableViewController {
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This way you don't have to hardcode the name of the storyboard and you can ensure storyboard and view controller are not nil and can be presented.